# Simple Practice Function Displays NaN

Tags: javascript, function, nan

```
function basketPrice(product, vat, delivery) {
    var total = product + vat + delivery;
    delivery = 7.5;
    vat = 20/100 * product;

    return total
}

basketPrice(150);
```

So just for the record I started looking into JavaScript about a week back so please excuse any dumb mistakes or lingo.

Above I am trying to generate a very simple output. I'm sure this isn't how you produce a basket on an e-commerce website, but it's just an example I'm using to help me practice.

I thought I had this down until my result was `NaN` (which I'm aware means Not a Number) but I have no idea which bit it is relating to and why.

I am looking for an explanation (as simple as possible) on where I've gone wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post inline code. I cant copy+ edit an image :/

Comment: Done, sorry didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function basketPrice(product, vat, delivery){
    console.log(product,vat,delivery);//150,undefined,undefined

  var total=product + vat + delivery;//150+undefined is not a number

 delivery=7.5;//now its to late to change sth
 vat = 0.2 * product;

 return total;
}

basketPrice(150);
```

Youre setting the variables after youve calculated total. So may use default values and/or set them before you calculate total:

```
function basketPrice(product, vat, delivery=7.5){

console.log(product,vat,delivery);//150,undefined,7.5

vat = vat || 0.2 * product;

 var total=product + vat + delivery;// is a number

 return total;
}
basketPrice(150);
basketPrice(1,2);
basketPrice(1,2,3);
```

---

If you actually dont want the two to be parameters, its much more simple:

```
function basketPrice(product){
 return product * 1.2 + 7.5;
}
```

or short:

```
basketPrice=p=>p*1.2+7.5;
```

Comment: Could you explain a couple things please?:

- why do you use the parameter val and how is it linking to the vat variable?
-why have you wrote vat = vat || (which i think means or) instead of just vat = 0.2 * product?

Comment: @lekens oh, no, what a typo :/

Comment: @11 1) typo sorry :/ , 2) maybe you want to change vat? So you could do basketPrice(1,2,3) and total will be 6

Comment: @Jonas w So why does the || (or) logical operator allow me to change vat? Cant I just changed the o.2 * product to 0.4 * product?

I'm not trying to sound patronizing I'm genuinely trying to learn :D

Comment: @11- vat = 5  || 6; is 5. vat = undefined || 6; is 6. so if vat is set, it takes vat, otherwise it takes 0.2* product..

Comment: @11- no thats fine. Its just simple math. Youre doing vat=product*0.2;total=product+vat+7.5; which can be joined to total=product+product*0.2+7.5; which can be joined to total=product*1.2+7.5

Comment: @Jonas w The penny just dropped as I was reading this, thanks for the further explanation. Seems simple now but it was the 1 being the product that was confusing me. You've been a great help Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a function that expects 3 arguments with just a single argument, so the calculation of total becomes NaN (Not a Number).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function basketPrice(product, delivery) { 
vat = (20/100 ) * product;
var total = product + vat + delivery; 
 return total;
} 
basketPrice(150,7.5);
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain why you don't make vat a parameter? is it so you don't have to set an argument for it?

Also the only price that would vary is the product's. So could i declare the delivery price inside the function also? Instead of using an argument?

Comment: @11- yes, if its not an argument, dont pass it.

Comment: @Jonas w apologies for being a pain but you've been a big help on this question Jonas w, by 'pass' you mean don't make it a parameter? 
Thank you.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Jonas w Had to look a couple thing sup in that shorthand >.< but makes sense to me now. The one thing I'm confused about is why you used 1.2 instead of 0.2 for the VaT? Typo? :D

Comment: @Jonas w I'm sorry but it's really not sinking in. If you have time to explain it a bit more in-depth that'd be really helpful. Sorry there's been so many follow-ups but I just want to wrap my head around it.

I'm worried this is going to become another question? If so just let me know and I'll re-post.